# XamlReader and Custom ContentPropertyAttribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a custom graphic layout engine. It's XAML-based and I thought about reusing the System.Xaml types to deal with the XAML.

As the objects are defined inside Portable Class Libraries, I cannot decorate them with the standard ContentPropertyAttribute and that is a problem, because I have to specify each content explicitly like this:

```
<Window> 
    <Window.Content>
        <TextBlock />    
    </Window.Content>    
</Window>
```

As you can appreciate, I set the TextBlock as Window.Content withing the <Window.Content> tags.

I would like it to work like it usually does:

```
<Window> 
    <TextBlock />            
</Window>
```

Can I configure the XamlReader/XamlObjectWriter to use a property by default when nothing is specified?